# In Django how can I filter objects in a QuerySet based on a many to many relationship?

Tags: python, django

So I have a user Profile model with a data attribute which is a many to many field representing a Profile "friending" another Profile like on Facebook. Here's the code for that:

```
friends = models.ManyToManyField("self")
```

What kind of query can I do to write a method that gets me all the Profiles that are friends with a current Profile?

```
friends = Profile.objects.filter(friends=self.pk)
```

This seems to give an empty QuerySet when I test it.

Comment: Can we apply many to many field in the same table?

Comment: Yep. It's currently working in the Django Admin panel I can edit the friendship status but I don't have a working way to access who is friends with who in my templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: 
For Django Querysets you use the double underscore __ to separate the attribute with other fields you want to check so in this case we're filtering the friends attribute where the pk is this Profile's pk.

```
friends = Profile.objects.filter(friends__pk=self.pk)
return friends
```

Comment: The related objects managers are pretty convenient and flexible too.  If you already have the 'person', person.friends_set.all() will returns this queryset; 
person.friends_set.set(friend__in=revised_list) will update the list of friendships.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/